# What does it mean to integrate with respect to matrices?

Tags: probability, integration, calculus

In Random matrix theory, the following definition of a partition function for an ensemble is common.
$$Z=\int dM \exp [-N Tr(M^2)]$$
where $M$ is a Random matrix of dimension $N \times N$.

In general, what does it mean to integrate with respect to a matrix, like this case.

Comment: An NxN matrix is determined by n^2 independent entries, so this is an integral over R^(n^2) with the standard measure. That’s all it means, sum (i.e. integrate) over all possible matrices parametrized by their entries.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I encountered this probablem in Random Matrix Theory, that's the reason I posted it here rather than Math StackExchange.